# How do I configure mongrels return mime types

Tags: mime, mongrel

How do I configure the content-types returned from mongrel. Speficially I want it to return some javascripts files as application/x-javascript to try and reproduce a bug I am seeing on a remote server

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly the answer that you are looking for but I found this by doing a quick google search. http://mongrel.rubyforge.org/wiki/HOWTO

It states that you can provide a yaml file with mime-types.